# (SQL) Adding elements in columns if they have the same name

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Name | Month | Price  
-------+---------+-------  
Gas , Jan , 21  
Gas , Feb , 40  
Food, Feb , 72  
Food, Apr , 56  
Food, Jan , 100  
Gas , Apr , 90  
Fun , Mar , 55
```

The new table should be:

```
Name | Price  
--------+-------  
Gas , 151  
Food , 228  
Fun , 55
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why is this labelled both MySQL and Postgres?  Please use the appropriate database tag for the database you are using.

Comment: @Senju please search first before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to get the desired result. It will insert the data in 2nd table by getting data from 1st table.

```
INSERT INTO your_table_2 (Name, Price)
SELECT Name, SUM(Price) as Price FROM table_name GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the `name` and then use an aggregate function like `sum()` to add up the `price`s for each distinct `name`

```
select name, sum(price) as total_price
from your_table
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new table from the aggregates, use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html).

```
CREATE TABLE AS
SELECT name, sum(price)::int AS price
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The cast to [`integer`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) (`::int`) is there, because Postgres returns [`bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) for a sum of integer values.